# What to use as "frequency error" when determining appropriate bandwidth for 2FSK?

Tags: rf, fsk

The datasheet for Semtech LLCC68 states, that when choosing appropriate bandwidth for 2FSK, one must obey the following constraint:

$$
Bandwidth[DSB] \geqslant bitrate + 2\cdot frequency\ deviation + frequency\ error
$$

It further states, that

> frequency error is two times the **crystal frequency error** used

The first two terms are from Carson's bandwidth rule, but what about "frequency error"?

If we follow the datasheet to the letter, we must use the maximum absolute error of the crystal frequency (in relation to its frequency, as stated in the spec). So, for example, for \$f_{xtal} = 32\ \mathrm{MHz}\$ and an error of 20 ppm, frequency error will be calculated as follows:

$$
f_{err} = \dfrac{32 * 10^6 * 20}{10^6} = 640\ \mathrm{Hz}
$$

This seems illogical, since in reality the "native" frequency of the crystal is not used directly (it is too low), but it is "upscaled" (don't know the correct word for it, but the crystal is used to drive the PLL at the desired higher frequency) to the operating frequency of the transceiver. For example, if we are operating in the 868 Mhz ISM band, then 868 MHz should be used in the numerator (obviously, "upscaling" the crystal's frequency to 868 MHz results in "upscaling" the error proportionally as well), so we get this:

$$
f_{err} = \dfrac{868 * 10^6 * 20}{10^6} = 17360\ \mathrm{Hz}
$$

Which one is correct? Intuitively, the second calculation seems to be correct, but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consideration regarding the **frequency error** is correct; the uncertainty of the reference oscillator's frequency gets scaled by the same factor as its frequency to the carrier.

So, you have an uncertainty of ca ± 17 kHz at 868 MHz.

**However**, you're probably incorrect on the bandwidth; frequency synchronization will probably correct the frequency offset, leaving you with the bandwidth error of the (equivalent, not necessarily physically manifest) baseband signal, and that would depend on the sampling frequency error.

I don't know the chip you mention well enough to tell you whether the sampling rate is identical to the crystal frequency, or derived as a multiple or fraction of that.